# Why doesn't this methods allow me to add to an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, push

I don't understand why my code below doesn't work  Could someone help me out?  I am trying to create a method that adds items to the end of an array.  I think my problem lies within my last line of code trying to access a local variable...  Thanks!

```
def add_to_array(name)
  array = []
  array << name
end

add_to_array("Rob")
add_to_array("Jack")

p array
```

Comment: You override `array` with a new array in each call of that method. Furthermore `array` is a local variable and not available outside of the method's scope.

Comment: So what would my solution be? Do I need to put array = [] outside the method? how would I print the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new array every time you call `add_to_array` method.
Besides that, this array is a *local variable* and has a scope limited to the `add_to_array` lifetime.

Try the following:

```
def add_to_array(array, name)
  array << name
end

array = []
add_to_array(array, "Rob")
add_to_array(array, "Jack")
p array
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  Would it be possible to create this with only one parameter in any way?

Comment: If `array` is an attribute of `object`, then you could call `object.add_to_array("Rob")`.

Comment: @RobMatthews to do it, the `add_to_array` variable must be able to see the `array` variable. This can be done in some ways. One of them is declare `array` prefixing it with `@`, like this: `@array = []`. I just created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/lucasrodcosta/21ba8b2d3193f6786e6813805bcd8bb3) with possible solutions. Hope it's useful =)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that you can't use `.push`? This is a default method for `Array`s in ruby

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push

```
array = Array.new
=> []

name = "Rob"
other_name = "Jack"
yet_another_name = "Jeff"

array.push(name)
=> ["Rob"]
array.push(other_name, yet_another_name)
=> ["Rob", "Jack", "Jeff]
```